Flutter Payment for product
Lets analyze this together. I created a learning app platform with flutter but my issue is that, I don't want the person to purchase the course more than once. Hence, when the person purchases it once, the next time the person tries to purchase it, the person would be redirected to the video of the course. Since the person has already paid for it. I had tried some few things and sometimes it gets the payment instance but then it would save it for all the other courses. I want each course payment to be tracked differently so that the user will know the one he/she has paid for. I used Firebase as the backend and paystack as the payment gateway
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:fancy_shimmer_image/fancy_shimmer_image.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_paystack/flutter_paystack.dart';
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/providers/orders_provider.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/screens/cart/cart_final.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/screens/order_bottom.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/screens/orders/order_done.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/screens/orders/orders_screen.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/services/global_methods.dart';
import 'package:new_customers_app/widgets/big_text.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import '../../inner_screens/product_details.dart';
import '../../model/cart_model.dart';
import '../../providers/cart_provider.dart';
import '../../providers/products_provider.dart';
import '../../providers/wishlist_provider.dart';
import '../../services/utils.dart';
import '../../widgets/favorite_btn.dart';
import '../../widgets/text_widget.dart';

class OrdersTest extends StatefulWidget {
  const OrdersTest({Key? key, required this.q}) : super(key: key);
  final int q;

  @override
  State<OrdersTest> createState() => _OrdersTestState();
}

class _OrdersTestState extends State<OrdersTest> {
  final _quantityTextController = TextEditingController();
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    _quantityTextController.text = widget.q.toString();
    plugin.initialize(publicKey: publicKey);
    getUserData();
    //_checkPurchase();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _quantityTextController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  TextEditingController amountController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();

  String publicKey = 'pk_test_7a83548a0e7d77d15ecff325478e34535c5446e3';
  final plugin = PaystackPlugin();
  String message = '';

  final TextEditingController _addressTextController =
      TextEditingController(text: "");
  bool _isLoading = false;

  void makePayment() async {
    
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                OrderDone()), // Replace LearningVideoScreen with your actual learning video screen
      );
      return;
    

    int price = int.parse(amountController.text) * 100;
    Charge charge = Charge()
      ..amount = price
      ..reference = 'ref_${DateTime.now()}'
      ..email = emailController.text
      ..currency = 'NGN';

    CheckoutResponse response = await plugin.checkout(
      context,
      method: CheckoutMethod.card,
      charge: charge,
    );

    if (response.status == true) {
      message = 'Payment Processing... Ref: ${response.reference}';
      

      
      if (mounted) {}
      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => _checkout(ctx: context)),
          ModalRoute.withName('/'));
    } else {
      print(response.message);
    }
  }

  String? _email;
  String? _name;
  String? address;
  final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;

  // method to fetch user data from firebase
  Future<void> getUserData() async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    if (user == null) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      return;
    }
    try {
      String _uid = user!.uid;

      final DocumentSnapshot userDoc =
          await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(_uid).get();
      if (userDoc == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        _email = userDoc.get('email');
        _name = userDoc.get('name');
        address = userDoc.get('shipping-address');
        _addressTextController.text = userDoc.get('shipping-address');
        
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
      // To create errorDialog method
      GlobalMethods.errorDialog(subtitle: '$error', context: context);
    } finally {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Color color = Utils(context).color;
    Size size = Utils(context).getScreenSize;
    final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(context);
    final cartModel = Provider.of<CartModel>(context);
    final getCurrProduct = productProvider.findProdById(cartModel.productId);
    final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(context);
    double usedPrice = getCurrProduct.isOnSale
        ? getCurrProduct.salePrice
        : getCurrProduct.price;
    final wishlistProvider = Provider.of<WishlistProvider>(context);
    bool? _isInWishlist =
        wishlistProvider.getWishlistItems.containsKey(getCurrProduct.id);

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pushNamed(context, ProductDetails.routeName,
            arguments: cartModel.productId);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  FancyShimmerImage(
                    imageUrl: getCurrProduct.imageUrl,
                    height: size.width * 0.18,
                    width: size.width * 0.25,
                    boxFit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  BigText(text: getCurrProduct.title)
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 15,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                controller: amountController
                  ..text = getCurrProduct.price.round().toString(),
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter the amount';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                    prefix: Text('NGN'),
                    hintText: '1000',
                    labelText: 'Amount',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                    enabled: false),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  controller: emailController..text = _email.toString(),
                  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                      return 'Please enter the email';
                    }
                    return _email;
                  },
                  decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'example@gmail.com',
                      labelText: 'Email',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      enabled: false),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: //hasPurchased
                      //?
                      () {
                    makePayment();
                   
                    // Code to do something else because the item is already purchased.
                    //print('Already purchased. Do something else.');
                  } //:
                  ,
                  child: Text(
                      
                      'Make Payment'),
                ),

                
              ),
            ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget _checkout({required BuildContext ctx}) {
  final Color color = Utils(ctx).color;
  Size size = Utils(ctx).getScreenSize;
  final cartProvider = Provider.of<CartProvider>(ctx);
  final productProvider = Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(ctx);
  final ordersProvider = Provider.of<OrdersProvider>(ctx);
  double total = 0.0;
  cartProvider.getCartItems.forEach((key, value) {
    final getCurrProduct = productProvider.findProdById(value.productId);
  });
  return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
    children: [
      SizedBox(
        height: 180,
      ),
      Icon(
        Icons.task_alt_outlined,
        size: 250,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      SizedBox(
        height: 80,
      ),
      Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
        Material(
            color: Colors.green,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            child: InkWell(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              onTap: () async {
                User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
                final orderId = const Uuid().v4();
                final productProvider =
                    Provider.of<ProductsProvider>(ctx, listen: false);
                // payment method here

                cartProvider.getCartItems.forEach((key, value) async {
                  final getCurrProduct = productProvider.findProdById(
                    value.productId,
                  );
                  try {
                    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('orders')
                        .doc(orderId)
                        .set({
                      'orderId': orderId,
                      'userId': user!.uid,
                      'productId': value.productId,
                      'price': (getCurrProduct.price) * value.quantity,
                      'totalPrice': total,
                      'quantity': value.quantity,
                      'imageUrl': getCurrProduct.imageUrl,
                      'userName': user.displayName,
                      'orderDate': Timestamp.now(),
                    });
                    await cartProvider.clearOnlineCart();
                    cartProvider.clearLocalCart();
                    ordersProvider.fetchOrders();
                    await Fluttertoast.showToast(
                      msg: "Payment Processing",
                      toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                      gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                    );
                  } catch (error) {
                    GlobalMethods.errorDialog(
                        subtitle: error.toString(), context: ctx);
                  } finally {}
                });
                Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                    ctx,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OrdersScreen()),
                    ModalRoute.withName('/'));
              },
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextWidget(
                  text: 'Click to Complete Payment',
                  textSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ))
      ])
    ],
  ));
}


Are you trying to figure out a way to know if a customer has paid for a product?

Affirmative. That's what am trying to do
